# InvalidOperationException: The firebase realtime database has not been properly initialized

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unity-game-engine

I have follow instruction from https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/blob/master/database/testapp/Assets/TestApp/UIHandler.cs

I tested ok on UnityEditor, but when I run on android device 
It throwing

`InvalidOperationException: The firebase realtime database has not been properly initialized.
11-12 10:39:31.724 28717 28760 I Unity   :   at Firebase.Database.Core.FirebaseConfigExtensions.CreatePlatform (Firebase.FirebaseApp app) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-12 10:39:31.724 28717 28760 I Unity   :   at Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.Context.GetPlatform () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-12 10:39:31.724 28717 28760 I Unity   :   at Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.Context.EnsureLogger () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-12 10:39:31.724 28717 28760 I Unity   :   at Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.Context.InitServices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-12 10:39:31.724 28717 28760 I Unity   :   at Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.Context.Freeze () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-12 10:39:31.724 28717 28760 I Unity   :   at Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.RepoManager.CreateLocalRepo (Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.Context ctx, Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.RepoInfo info, Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-12 10:39:31.724 28717 28760 I Unity   :   at Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.RepoManager.CreateRepo (Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.Context ctx, Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.RepoInfo info, Firebase.Database.Fireba`

I found no suggest for this problem. Any ideal for this?

I tested with auth and analytic, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is Striping Level in PlayerSettings.
When I return it to "Disable" everything work. [image: Cannot to be apply optimization when using Firebase Realtime Database]